# Panels Vs LayoutPanles in GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt, gwt2, layoutpanels

I'm a newbie to GWT.And i wonder when to use panels and when to use layout panels.I'm really confused.Can anyone provide a legit use case , where we need to use panels instead of layout panels and vice versa?.Thanks.

Comment: You should start reading here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html

Answer (score 1):

When you need a child to take its initial size from a parent and then resize when a parent resizes, use a LayoutPanel or another panel that implements ProvidesResize() interface. This way, for example, you can split the browser window into top menu and main area parts, and make the main area change its size as the browser windows is resized.

When you want a panel to take its size from its own content, use HTMLPanel or FlowPanel.